# How to query last n months average while grouping by a different field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
deviceid  year  month   value
432       2019  3       2571
432       2019  2       90
432       2019  1       314
432       2018  12      0
432       2018  11      100
437       2019  2       0
437       2019  1       1
437       2018  12      0
437       2018  11      3
437       2018  10      2
437       2018  9       0
437       2018  8       2
```

I need a query that for each deviceId retrieves the average value for the last 3 months.
Eg:

```
deviceId  Average
432       991.7
437       0.3
```

I'm quite sure i have to use partitions or something similar.

Im thinking it should look something like this, but I can't figure out how to get the average value of just the last 3 months.

```
select deviceId, avg(value) from Table group by deviceid
```

Comment: Do you want the last 3 months before this month (i.e. 2019 Feb, Mar, Apr), from this month (i.e. 2019 Mar, Apr, May), or alternatively the most recent 3 months in the database for each device (i.e. device 432 = 2019 month 3, 2, 1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ROW_NUMBER to figure out which months are the last 3 per deviceid.

Sample Data:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (deviceid INT, year INT, month INT, value NUMERIC(12,2))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
(432, 2019 , 3 ,2571),
(432, 2019 , 2 ,90  ),
(432, 2019 , 1 ,314 ),
(432, 2018 , 12,0   ),
(432, 2018 , 11,100 ),
(437, 2019 , 2 ,0   ),
(437, 2019 , 1 ,1   ),
(437, 2018 , 12,0   ),
(437, 2018 , 11,3   ),
(437, 2018 , 10,2   ),
(437, 2018 , 9 ,0   ),
(437, 2018 , 8 ,2   )
```

Query:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT deviceid, value, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY deviceid ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC) rn
    FROM @t
)
SELECT deviceid, AVG(value) average
FROM cte
WHERE rn BETWEEN 1 AND 3
GROUP BY deviceid
```

Returns:

```
deviceid    average
432         991.666666
437         0.333333
```

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what i was looking for, I didn't realize that i had to use the window function in a separate query and then group, was trying to do both at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to calculate a date from you `year` and `month` columns to use for comparison.

```
DECLARE @ComparisonDate DATE = '20190301'; 
--Or, perhaps, EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1) to get the last day of last month?

SELECT 
  deviceId,
  AVG(value) AS AvgValue
FROM
  @t as t
WHERE
  DATEFROMPARTS(year,month,1) >= DATEADD(MONTH,-3,@ComparisonDate)
GROUP BY
  deviceId;
```